# Merge Overlapping Array in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can we merge overlapping array into one using spark.

```
    ids 
    ---------
    [1,2,3]
    [2,3,4]
    [2,3]
    [6,7,8,9]
```

The expected output is like:

```
    ids 
    ---------
    [1,2,3,4]
    [6,7,8,9]
```

How can we achieve above output using spark?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried with simple groupby however I am new to scala-spark. Can you help me on that?

Comment: This kind of needs more Inputs. Couple of questions
1: What is the Size of RDD[Seq[Int]]] that you would want in output
2: By overlapping do u mean consecutive arrays in RDD
3: .distinct is going to ensure that the RDD contains distinct Elements. Is that what you are looking for?
4: Are u using RDD or Dataframe?
I think once these questions are answered it would be easier to answer your question

Comment: 1. Number of input records = 6 millions
2. not neccessary consecutive array. ex. [1,5,7], [7,2,1] = [1,2,5,7]
3. I am looking for merging arrays if any element exists
4. I am using RDD for now

Comment: Please define "overlapping" with some examples and edit your question. Also add it to the question that your expected output array size is 4 if it is the case.